# найти слово в сниппете, используя гитхук (питон)

Tags: python, githooks

как при помощи написанного с нуля хука на питоне, искать какое-то конкретное слово в коде, котором мы коммитим?

Я смог понять, как проделать подобное с сообщением коммита, но как внутри гитхука добраться до кода, подлежащего коммиту, не знаю.
Вот пример как, я открыл commit message:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

def main():
  print(f"Number of arguments: {len(sys.argv)}")
  print(f"Argument List: {str(sys.argv)}")
  with open(sys.argv[1],"r") as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()

    for line in lines:
      print(line)

  sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: какое отношение к вопросу имеют интерпретатор python и сервер github.com? // изложите это прямо в тексте вопроса, пожалуйста, нажав [edit]

Comment: Извините, если отвечу неправильно, недостаточно просвещен в этих вещах. Гитхаб, я в самом деле зря приплел, тут скорее просто гит, а интерпретатор питона связан с тем, что я пишу на нём гитхук.

Comment: ну вот вам целый вагон примеров обращения к файлам, которые включены в коммит: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks